# Determine Y-parameters for given circuit. [Used Nodal Analysis]

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, network, port, nodal-analysis

I am trying to solve this circuit for past 3 hours, no success, so I am posting here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYrfpB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used nodal analysis, I will go over the equations I got;

->To find `y11 & y21` lets short V2 and apply a current source at V1,also after identifying nodes; we get

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK2OM5.png)</sup>

Now Equation for `Vo`;

```
I2-2io = (2/3)Vo - (1/6)V1
```

At `V2`, We determine `I2 = -(1/2)Vo` So `Vo` becomes;

```
2io = (7/6)Vo - (1/6)V1 --> EQ-1
```

Now for node `V1`; I get ;

```
I1 - io = (1/2)V1 - (1/6)Vo --> EQ-2
```

Now that I got these EQ-1 & EQ-2; I am not getting right answers, I got different answers all the time.
Kindly help me solve this circuit for Y parameters using nodal analysis.Any sort of help will be appreciated.

**In my book**; I get `y11=0.625S`,since im not getting `y11` right so I didnt bother to solve this problem for `y21` and so on.

Comment: Show your equations, using ONLY variables. No resistance values, no fixed-ratio in the controlled-source.

Comment: lets say controlled source is X, so at Vo i get;
`I2-X = (1/R2 + 1/R3)Vo - (1/R2)V1`